New emulator instances spawned when stopping
Every time I stop the emulator via Android Studio Virtual Device Manager or close it in the Running Devices side panel there are seemingly spawed one to mostly two new instances. This is after three boots and closes:

Why is this?

OS: Debian Trixie
Emulator: 34.2.16
SDK platform-tools: 35.0.1


Have you use a process viewer like htop in tree mode to see which process spawns the new emulator instances?

At first it is spawned by the right emulator process itself but when it terminates, the weird two subprocesses that look the same jump to systemd it the tree

It's solved for me by launching with ./emulator -avd Pixel_8_API_34-ext12 -feature -Vulkan -netdelay none -netspeed full -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token from cmd (-feature -Vulkan is unrelated). It doesn't matter if stopping in Android Studio or with ^C. Don't know if this will help someone ...
